# How to add an empty row on top of the header row in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Problem:

Let there be a dataframe with multiple columns,

```
A  |  B  |  C  | ....
2  |  b  |  c  |
3  |  c  |  b  |
.
.
.
```

where A, B and C are the headers

Output:

```
   |     |     |....
A  |  B  |  C  | 
2  |  b  |  c  |
3  |  c  |  b  |
.
.
.
```

Is there an efficient way to add an empty row over the header row in the dataframe?

I have found a way to add an empty row right after the header row but I am able to find a way to add an empty row over the header row. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how do you access the columns if you create an empty row?

Comment: eventually I want to add excel formulas via xlsxwriter in those empty rows

Comment: i don't need to access the columns because i don't need to make any changes to the dataframe after inserting an empty row..

Comment: Can't you write in a row of excel formulas with xlsxwriter, then just append your data to that sheet once you've written those formulas in?

Comment: let me try this approach..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try after adding - sorting?:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='B')
```